# How to set the conditions for displaying of the related-products

Tags: module, collection, query, related-products

Overriding related-product collection. My aim is to set limit for related product display. Related-products are not displayed if there are less than 10 products, the maximum number of products that can be displayed - 20, more than 20 related-products should not be displayed. But if there are less than 10 products,  do not need to display related-products at all.

I need support, please explain or show details, how can I do this using *sql queries* in a collection ? (not a template) Here is my class in which I am trying to do this:

```
class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related
{

    /**
     * I set limit here 
     */
    const RELATED_LIMIT = 20;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart $checkoutCart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutCart = $checkoutCart;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutCart,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $checkoutSession,
            $moduleManager,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data
     * added limit for collection
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'required_options'
        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

        //limit number of products
        $this->_itemCollection->setPageSize(self::RELATED_LIMIT);

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
        $this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to not display related product if count is less than 10,
override `getItems()` function in your preference file as below

```
/**
 * Get collection items
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getItems()
{
    if ($this->_itemCollection === null) {
        $this->_prepareData();
    }
    // code to check collection size
    if($this->_itemCollection->getSize() < 10){
        $this->_itemCollection = null;
    }   
    return $this->_itemCollection;
}
```